# Basic SQL statement , select staff name from staff table

Tags: sql

Here is the requirement

I have two tables like below, OrderList is a data table which include 3 fields stored StaffId which is a foreign key from staff table. Noted that some records may not have a value in this table.

**OrderList**

```
OrderId Marketing_Staff_ID Finance_Staff_Id ManagerId
1       STAFF001           STAFF002         STAFF003
2                          STAFF005         STAFF003
3       STAFF004           STAFF004         STAFF003
4       STAFF001           STAFF002         STAFF003
5       STAFF001                            STAFF007
```

**Staff**

```
Staff_Id Staff_Name
STAFF001 Jack C.K.
STAFF002 William. C
STAFF005 Someone
```

I want to write a SQL statement can also select staff name for each record form OrderList, (For these records without staff ID, leave N/A in the name field)

```
OrderId Mkt StaffID Name       Finance StaffId  Name      ManagerId, Name
1       STAFF001    Jack C.K.  STAFF002         William.  STAFF003   Chan.Chi
```

So how can I write the SQL? Left join or sth?

Thank you very much as I am really a beginner in SQL.

Answer (score 5):

You need multiple `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
select ol.orderid,
       ol.marketing_staff_id,
       coalesce(ms.staff_name, 'n/a') as marketing_name,
       ol.finance_staff_id,
       coalesce(fi.staff_name, 'n/a') as finance_name
from orderlist as ol
  left join staff as ms on ms.staff_id = ol.marketing_staff_id
  left join staff as fi on fi.staff_id = ol.finance_staff_id
```

I'll leave it up to you to add the join for the manager.

The above is ANSI SQL and should work in every DBMS. There is a slight possibility that your DBMS does not support the `coalesce` function which simply replaces a `NULL` value with something different. You will need to check the manual of your DBMS in that case.